# How to make a proper Java makefile?

Tags: java, makefile

I need to make a makefile for a Java project.

My project is basic. A package which contains my main file and some others packages.

Can someone help me to make a proper makefile for that kind of project ?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/javamakefiles.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: I think the question is vague. What did you try?

Comment: Does it have to be _make_? Can you use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)?

Comment: Can't use ant. I just want to compile my source .java to a java executable

Comment: Thanks Smit, it is what I am looking for. But I still have some issues.
When a "make" I get that kind of error :

java:5: error: package myPackage.PacketComparator does not exist

However, this package and this class exists ..

Comment: Ant has a simple `javac` task...

Comment: Perhaps you need to indicate where to find all sources of your project by adding -sourcepath <src-dir> to the 'javac' command. That said I am with others about using ant or maven.

Comment: By the way? what is your build supposed to produce? A jar file containing all classes? Does it has a main class and the jar file has to be auto-executable?

Comment: In general you should use ant or maven which are supposed build tools in java projects (even those simple). Makefiles are rather from C/ C++ world.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have not tested so it is likely to fail...

Assuming that what you need is to generate a executable jar file the following should work but I have not tested it.

The Makefile below assumes that your sources are located under ./src and that you are happy to use ./build for intermediary files (which is totally obliterated by the clean target so be careful).

Then 'make' or 'make jar' should generate the jar file.

```
  NAME=MyProject

  MAIN_CLASS=MyMainClass

  SRC_DIR=./src
  CLS_DIR=./build/classes
  MANIFEST_FILE=./build/META-INF.MF
  JAR_FILE=./$(NAME).jar

  SRC_FILES=$(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -iname "*.java")
  CLS_FILES=$(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(CLS_DIR)/%,$(patsubst %.java,%.class,$(SRC_FILES)))

  .PHONY: jar run clean mrproper

  jar : $(JAR_FILE)

  run : $(JAR_FILE)
        java -jar $(JAR_FILE)

  $(JAR_FILE) : $(MANIFEST_FILE) $(CLS_FILES)
        jar cmf $< $@ $(CLS_DIR)    


  $(MANIFEST_FILE) :
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        echo Main-Class: $(MAIN_CLASS) > $@

  $(CLS_DIR) :
        mkdir -p $(CLS_DIR)

  $(CLS_DIR)/%.class : $(SRC_DIR)/%.java $(CLS_DIR)
        javac -d $(CLS_DIR) -sourcepath $(SRC_DIR) $<

  clean : 
        rm -Rf ./build

  mrproper : clean
        rm -f $(JAR_FILE)
```

Each time you execute Make it performs a find operation to get the list of source files, that might cause some delay depending on how many files and how fast is the file-system.... but you said is is a small project so it should not be an issue.

The double patsubst might well be compressed into a single one but I did it in two steps just in case.

Also notice that this solution compiles each Java class separately. This can be quite costly and it might be advisable to have another target to compile all at once ideally by creating a file that contains the name of all src java files and passing it to javac.